# How to get EXIF attributes that Android ExifInterface cannot find？

Tags: android, exif, android-exifinterface

I am trying to read the EXIF information of images taken by a UAV (more specifically, DJI Mavic 2).

I have sucessfully get some attributes ( "GPS Altitude","GPS Longitude","GPS Latitude") by using `ExifInterface`.

However, I realize that `ExifInterface` is missing some attributes.

For example, I can't get "Relative Altitude", "Gimbal Roll Degree", "Gimbal Yaw Degree","Gimbal Pitch Degree", etc., although I can see these attributes on PC using some other software(exiftool for example).

**How can I get these EXIF information?**

Comment: `"GPS Latitude"`  ?   There is `ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE` and so on. Please reformulate your post as i have no idea what you man with `some attributes are not listed in ExifInterface`.

Comment: @blackapps I know there is `ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE` and I have successfully get it. If you check the EXIF info of the image using some other software(exiftool for example) on PC, the actual name of `ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE` is "GPS latitude". However, I cannot find attributes like "Gimbal Roll Degree", "Relative Altitude" using ExifInterface, although I can find them using exiftool on PC.

Comment: You have not cleared up anything. And you talk about a windows program instead of mentioning tags the way ExifInterFace does it. And you did not write a better post but used a comment. Difficult talking this way.

Comment: @blackapps I think I have made it clear: I have a image that is proven to have the following EXIF attributes: GPS Longitude, GPS Latitude, Gimbal Roll Degree, Relative Altitude. However the android ExifInterface can only get part of them, and I want to get all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up ExifInterface and solved this by reading the raw bytes as HEX and parse the HEX into EXIF information.

I also found a library [here](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) that should work, but didn't have a try as the issue was already solved.